# JavaScript Class, raise events?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm lost.  I'm trying to do a class similar to below, at a specific time in the class I need to be able to report back via firing an event that something was completed.  Yet it doesn't appear JS has events?  Could someone shed some light on this topic for me please?

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {}

    test() {
       // Do Stuff
       // RAISE EVENT: onTest
    }
}

-------------------------
script.js
-------------------------
let myClass = new MyClass();

// Register the event listener here?
// myClass on event onTest () = {dostuff;}

myClass.test();
```

Comment: That’s correct: the language itself doesn’t have built-in events. There are a few different ways to implement them. Are you targeting Node.js or a browser? Are you familiar with the use of packages (from npm)?

Comment: Straight browser, I'm familiar with npm packaging a little, python/php/.net packaging as well (meaning I get the concept lol).  This class will be a script that provides a common set of functionality for an application via TamperMonkey, which is why it's browser

Comment: If you want to work in both node & browser, you could look at -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you could use the built in `events` and apply them to the document and just use `addeventlistener` for that event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor() {}

    test() {
       document.dispatchEvent(new Event('tested'));
    }
}

let myClass = new MyClass();

document.addEventListener('tested', function (e) { console.log("tested!") }, false);

myClass.test();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, just tested, does what I wanted.